# python how to iterate a variable which consists of multiple lists

Tags: python

I have a variable that consists of the list after list after list

my code:

```
>>> text = File(txt) #creates text object from text name
>>> names = text.name_parser() #invokes parser method to extract names from text object
```

My name_parser() stores names into a list self.names=[]

example:

```
>>> variable = my_method(txt)
```

output:

```
>>> variable 
>>> [jacob, david], [jacob, hailey], [judy, david], ...
```

I want to make them into single list while retaining the duplicate values

desired output:

```
>>> [jacob, david, jacob, hailey, judy, david, ...]
```

(edited)
(edited)

Comment: Please, check [ask] and provide [mre]. your first lien `variable = [a,b,c], [d,e,f], [g,h,i]` is not valid, because `a`, `b`, etc. are not defined. Then it's not clear where e.g. `one.txt` comes from.

Comment: This is a *tuple*

Comment: sorry about the confusion. I made edits hopefully it's more clear

Answer (score 2):

Here's a very simple approach to this.

```
variable = [['a','b','c'], ['d','e','f'], ['g','h','i']]
fileNames = ['one.txt','two.txt','three.txt']
dict = {}
count = 0
for lset in variable:
    for letters in lset:dict[letters] = fileNames[count]
    count += 1
print(dict)
```

Comment: don't use `dict` as name, it's a built-in function.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

#function to iterate through the list of dict

def fun(a):

    for i in a:
        for ls in i:
            f = open(ls)
            for x in f:
                print(x)

variable ={ "a": "text.txt", "b": "text1.txt" , "c":"text2.txt" , "d": "text3.txt"}

myls = [variable["a"], variable["b"]], [variable["c"], variable["d"]]

fun(myls)

print("Execution Completed")
```

Comment: You 're welcome, and welcome to Stack Overflow. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools` module that will allow to transform your list of lists into a flat list:

```
import itertools

foo = [v for v in itertools.chain.from_iterable(variable)]
```

After that you can iterate over the new variable however you like.

Comment: this outputs each string in lists into characters
example:
variable = [abc,def], [ghi,jkl], ...

output:
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
['g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l']

desired output:
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l']

(sorry for the confusion, I will edit my question)

Comment: `[x for x in whatever]` -> `list(whatever)`

Answer (score 0):

Well, if your variable is list of lists, then you can try something like this:

```py
file_dict = {}

for idx, files in enumerate(variable):
    # you can create some dictionary to bind indices to words 
    # or use any library for this, I believe there are few
    file_name = f'{idx+1}.txt'
    for file in files:
        file_dict[file] = [file_name]
```